# Removing notifications of other apps using deleteIntent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm using `NotificationListenerService` to read the notifications posted by other apps. In `onNotificationPosted` I get the `deleteIntent` of the notification and call `deleteIntent.send()` to remove the notification. This doesn't work for notifications posted by some apps! I have tried removing them using `cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId())`, but this also fails to remove them.

When swiping a notification on a phone or on a watch removes the notification from the phone, I expect firing `deleteIntent` explicitly, remove the notification as well.

Any ideas on why some notifications can't be removed?

Answer (score 0):

The `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` has been set which prevents the notification from being cancelled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html
if `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` is set, the notification cannot be canceled when the user clicks the Clear all button. I just did a quick test. While I can't remove the notification programmatically by firing its `deleteIntent`, pressing Clear all button removed. it. Thus, the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` is not set for the notification I'm trying to delete.